kafka-clients 3.4.0 Node X disconnected messages frequently
the log【INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node X disconnected】.
springboot version is 2.7.18
kafka-clents version is 3.4.0
the producer all are working fine. is the info message harmful to the application?
Can you tell me how to fix it, thanks very much.
